# Save the rendered tweet, or the raw <blockquote> to database?

Tags: cms, content, data, user-generated-content, twitter-card

I have a CMS where authors write articles, and the text editor allows for embedded tweets.

Embedded tweets normally consist of a `<blockquote>` element with raw text of the tweet, requiring an additional script provided by Twitter, which then renders that blockquote into the visually styled tweet that users get to see on the page.

In the first step, where authors are writing the article in the CMS, I have a choice of rendering that tweet in the text editor immediately, so that the authors can see the rendered result while writing the article. As a consequence, this would also post the rendered tweet to the backend, to be saved into the database. My question is, would this be a bad thing to do? Or is it important to leave it to Twitter to render the tweet live, so that I would let them potentially change how they render it in the future, I guess? (or maybe there are some other reasons too)